# WILDFLY 11: jboss-modules.jar more than one, but the DV can't be accessed

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

[standalone more than 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/597uK.jpg)

[jboss-moduless.jar more than 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34zcZ.jpg)

the condition is jboss-modules.jar more than one services. But the DV can't be accessed.
error notif from client is "TEIID Error establishing socket to host and port: localhost:31000. Reason: null"

when i kill watch, standalone.sh, and java,  jboss-modules.jar still activating automatically until more than one like on picture.

Comment: Hey, your question doesn't make clear what exactly your problem is. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to improve your question. Also, you can embed the code that you posted as images directly in your question, to make it easier for others to read it.

Comment: Hey, your question doesn't make clear what exactly your problem is. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to improve your question. Also, you can embed the code that you posted as images directly in your question, to make it easier for others to read it.